# Alternative for count()

Tags: sql-server

I have used the `count()` function to calculate each of the rows values

```
select course, count(*) course_count from student_table
group by course;
```

Without using `count()` is there any alternative to accomplish this?

Comment: How about `Sum(1)`

Comment: Do you have a requirement? Or just curiosity?

Comment: Yes this question was for a requirement at my workplace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SUM(1)` instead:

```
SELECT
    course,
    SUM(1) AS course_count
FROM student_table
GROUP BY
    course;
```

`SUM(1)` happens to behave the same way as count here, because it sums 1 for each record.  However, `COUNT` in fact is the semantically correct function to use here.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the below way.

```
CREATE TABLE Account
( Account_id Int, AccountName varchar(20));

INSERT INTO Account (Account_id, AccountName) 
Values (1, 'Test'), (2, 'Test A'), (3, 'Test A'), (4, 'Test C'), (5, 'Test D')

Select AccountName, Max(CntTotal) as CntTotal from(
Select AccountName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By AccountName Order By AccountName) as CntTotal
from Account
)a group by AccountName
```

[**Online Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=26bab8b81cfef17e09b60a75c93d38c7)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adventure Work means, try this:

```
with CTE as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by PurchaseOrderID)as RR from Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
)

select * from CTE where RR>=1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).